# Удаление строки таблицы JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Всем здравствуйте, столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Необходимо при нажатии на чекбокс в конкретной строке таблицы удалять эту строку из таблицы. Использую конструкцию

```
checkbox.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var row1 = document.getElementById("checkbox_id").parentNode.parentNode;
    });
```

Так я получаю строку. Но получаю не ту строку, в которой жму чекбокс, а первую. Это первый мой косяк. А второй - не могу понять как ее удалить. Понимаю, что нужно использовать `removeChild`, но собрать это воедино не выходит. Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  var row;
  row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.setAttribute("id", "tr_id");
  var cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.setAttribute("id", "td1_id");
  td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));

  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  td2.setAttribute("id", "td2_id");
  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkbox.setAttribute("id", "checkbox_id");
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var row1 = document.getElementById("checkbox_id").parentNode.parentNode;
    //        row1.parentNode.removeChild(row1);
    console.log(row1);
  });
  td2.appendChild(checkbox);

  var td3 = document.createElement("td");
  td3.setAttribute("id", "td3_id");
  td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));

  var td4 = document.createElement("td");
  td4.setAttribute("id", "td4_id");
  td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));

  var td5 = document.createElement("td");
  td5.setAttribute("id", "td5_id");
  td5.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));

  var td6 = document.createElement("td");
  td6.setAttribute("id", "td6_id");
  var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
  btnEdit.setAttribute("class", "btnEdit");
  btnEdit.src = "icons/edit.png";
  btnEdit.type = "image";
  btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editButton();
    return false;
  });
  td6.appendChild(btnEdit);

  var deleteButton = document.createElement("input");
  deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "deleteButton");
  deleteButton.src = "icons/delete.png";
  deleteButton.type = "image";
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    delButton();
    return false;
  });
  td6.appendChild(deleteButton);
  td6.setAttribute("colspan", "2");
  row.appendChild(td1);
  row.appendChild(td2);
  row.appendChild(td3);
  row.appendChild(td4);
  row.appendChild(td5);
  row.appendChild(td6);
  tbody.appendChild(row);

  localStorage.setItem("ShoppingList", document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tbody id="tbody">
      <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
        <td>
          <font color="white">#</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">Done</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">Item</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">Quantity</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">Price $</font>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="100">
          <font color="white">Action</font>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Видимо у вас много эллементов с одинаковым id "checkbox_id"

Comment: Действительно, в каждой строке чекбокс имеет один и тот же id...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что бы вам получить доступ к элементу, который вызвал функцию вам надо

```
checkbox.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var checkboxElement = e.target; // элемент который вызвал функцию
    });
```

либо

```
checkbox.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var checkboxElement = this; // элемент который вызвал функцию
    });
```

Что бы удалить элемент надо

```
ell.parentElement.removeChild(ell);
```

в вашем случае

```
ell = checkboxElement.parent.parent; // tr element (ваша строчка)
ell.parentElement.removeChild(ell); // удаляем всю строку
```

или более красиво

```
ell = checkboxElement.closest("tr"); // tr element (ваша строчка)
ell.parentElement.removeChild(ell); // удаляем всю строку
```

Answer (score 3):

Без привязки к id :

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')).forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var a = this.closest('tr');
    a.parentElement.removeChild(a);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="table" style="background-color:black;">
  <table class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tbody id="tbody">
      <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
        <td>
          <font color="white">#</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">Done</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">Item</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">Quantity</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">Price $</font>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="100">
          <font color="white">Action</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">Remove</font>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
        <td>
          <font color="white">1</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">1</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">1</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">1</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <font color="white">1</font>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="100">
          <font color="white">1</font>
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>

        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <td>
            <font color="white">2</font>
          </td>
          <td>
            <font color="white">2</font>
          </td>
          <td>
            <font color="white">2</font>
          </td>
          <td>
            <font color="white">2</font>
          </td>
          <td>
            <font color="white">2</font>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100">
            <font color="white">2</font>
          </td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Ваш вариант работает, но для меня, как для новичка, более понятен ответ Дмитрия Полянина, поэтому я решил воспользоваться пока именно им.